# Can't get list of model fields

Tags: python, mongodb, umongo

I need to get list of model fields like:

```
@instance.register
class Todo(Document):
    title = fields.StringField(required=True, default='Name')
    description = fields.StringField()
    created_at = fields.DateTimeField()
    created_by = fields.StringField()
    priority = fields.IntegerField()
```

to

```
[
    'title',
    'description',
    'created_at',
    'created_by',
    'priority'
]
```

So, I have function that returns list of fields

```
def get_class_properties(cls):
    attributes = inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda a: not (inspect.isroutine(a)))
    return [attr for attr in attributes if not (attr[0].startswith('__') and attr[0].endswith('__'))][1]
```

But usage gives me this error
`umongo.exceptions.NoDBDefinedError: init must be called to define a db`

Usage:
`properties=get_class_properties(Todo)`

**UPD**
Here is my mongo initialization code:

```
async def mongo_client(app):
    conf = app["config"]["mongo"]
    client = AsyncIOMotorClient(host=conf["host"], port=conf["port"])
    db = client[conf["db"]]
    instance.init(db)
    await Todo.ensure_indexes()
    app["db_client"]: AsyncIOMotorClient = client
    app["db"] = db
    yield
    await app["db_client"].close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was that

`properties=get_class_properties(Todo)`

invokes earlier than

`async def mongo_client(app):`

Solution is use things in right order (see comments to code)

```
async def init_app(argv=None):
    app = web.Application(middlewares=[deserializer_middleware], logger=logger)
    app["config"] = config

    conf = app["config"]["mongo"]
    client = AsyncIOMotorClient(host=conf["host"], port=conf["port"])
    db = client[conf["db"]]
    instance.init(db)
    # Remove this line:
    # app.cleanup_ctx.append(mongo_client)
    app.cleanup_ctx.append(api_client)

    register_routes(app)
    return app
```

```
def register_routes(app: web.Application):
    # Use here:
    todo_resource = RestResource(
        entity='todo',
        factory=Todo,
        properties=get_class_properties(Todo)
    )
    todo_resource.register(app.router)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy/paste of [this answer](https://github.com/Relrin/sanic-mongodb-extension/issues/7#issuecomment-457811493) from the author of [this library](https://github.com/Relrin/sanic-mongodb-extension/issues/7):

> As far as I remeber, this exception raises when you're trying to use
>   lazy clients without initializing them properly. Any lazy class of
>   uMongo expects that the used database will be specified before the
>   usage. Everything that you need is to specify the used database and
>   invoke the init method of your lazy instance, like this:
>
> ```
> from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient
> from umongo import MotorAsyncIOInstance
>
> client = AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://user:password@host:port/")
> client = client["test_database"]
> lazy_umongo = MotorAsyncIOInstance()
> lazy_umongo.init(client)
> ```
>
> As an example you can look into [Auth/Auth microservice](https://github.com/OpenMatchmaking/microservice-auth) code, where
>   documents defined and store in the separate files from the actual
>   usage. Also these files with code as examples ([documents.py](https://github.com/OpenMatchmaking/microservice-auth/blob/master/auth/app/microservices/documents.py) and
>   [prepare_mongodb.py](https://github.com/OpenMatchmaking/microservice-auth/blob/master/auth/app/commands/prepare_mongodb.py#L50-L53)) will help you to find a solution.